# How to set Monaco editor inline font size?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, editor, monaco-editor

I want to have the effect like this:

[image]

So I use `editor.deltaDecorations()` to edit inline css class.
this is my code

```
var content = [
    'xxx line 1 xxx',
    'xxx title xxx',
    'xxx line 3 xxx'
].join('\n');

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: content,
    language: 'plaintext'
});

var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations(
    [],
    [
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(2, 4, 2, 10),
            options: {
                inlineClassName: 'myclass'
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

css

```
.myclass {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

The result is

[image]

Monaco editor changed the font size, but didn't recalculate the height of line，how to solve this problem? help !

Answer (score 3):

The Monaco editor is a code editor, which implies some conditions. Some of them are:

1. The entire editor uses the same font.
2. The editor does not consider CSS styles for line computation.
3. Monospaced fonts work best.
4. Its main purpose is to display program code, which must be easy to read. Hence different fonts or font styles are rather distracting.

Monaco Editor is not a rich text editor. Use a different control if you want that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Do you have a good open source rich text editor recommendation? @Mike

Comment: Software recommendations are not acceptable here at SO. Instead use your favourite search engine to check the options that exist.